# Create A View Using Dynamic Sql

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to create a dynamic database creation script.

There are a lot of steps and we create this database often so the script looks something like this.

```
 DECLARE @databaseName nvarchar(100) = 'DatabaseName'
 EXEC('/*A lot of database creation code built off of @databaseName*/')
```

This is all well and good except for one view that we'd like to create in `@databaseName`.

I've tried four different ways to create this view without success:

1. My first thought was to simply set the database context and then create the view in one script. Unfortunately, this didn't work because `CREATE VIEW` must be the first statement in its query block ([details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks)).

   ```
   --Result: Error message, "'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch"
   EXEC 
   ('
       USE [' + @databaseName + ']
       CREATE VIEW
   ')
   ```
2. To get around (1) I tried to set the context separately so that `CREATE VIEW` would be the first command in the `EXEC`. This did create the view but did so within my current context and not `@databaseName`. It seem that the effects of calling `USE` in `EXEC` only persist until the end of that `EXEC` statement ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3788672/1066291)).

   ```
   --Result: The view is created in the currently active database rather than @databaseName
   EXEC ('USE [' + @databaseName + ']')
   EXEC ('CREATE VIEW')
   ```
3. Next I tried putting everything back into one script but included a `GO` command in order to make `CREATE VIEW` the first command in a new query block. This failed because `GO` isn't allowed within an `EXEC` script ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14473223/1066291)).

   ```
   --Result: Error message, "Incorrect syntax near 'GO'"
   EXEC 
   ('
       USE [' + @databaseName + ']
       GO
       CREATE VIEW
   ')
   ```
4. Finally I tried to specify the target database as part of the `CREATE VIEW` command. In this case the script failed because `CREATE VIEW` doesn't allow the database to be specified as part of its creation ([details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#syntax)).

   ```
   --Result: Error message, "'CREATE/ALTER VIEW' does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name"
   EXEC ('CREATE VIEW [' + @databaseName + '].[dbo].[ViewName]')
   ```

Any suggestions? I think this should be a common use case but Google wasn't able to help me.

Comment: Couldn't you just say CREATE VIEW {database}.{schema}.{viewname} ... ?

Comment: Can you do that? I thought when CREATING VIEWS you can only qualify down to the schema (from MSDN: cl.ly/image/2j001P3m3F3V). I guess I could always try it instead of just assuming I fully understand the documentation.

Comment: Another option is to generate a `.sql` file and use `sqlcmd` to execute it.  More complicated in some ways and less in others for what you are doing.  Primarily though it acts just like a SQL file you are going to run yourself.  Among other things you can use `GO`.

Comment: Good idea but at that point I think we might as well do a find and replace all on [DatabaseName] and not use dynamic sql at all. That's what we originally had but sometimes not everything was updated and resulted in problems so I wanted a one stop update. We really wanted to make this a one step process instead of a 6 or so step process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me Mark

```
EXEC [OtherDatabase].[sys].[sp_ExecuteSQL] N'CREATE VIEW [SM].[vMyView] AS SELECT ...'
```

I ran this from the context of the master database and successfully created a new view in the OtherDatabase.

Comment: Awesome thank you. Here is another good answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21173560/1066291